# escaping bracket in postgresql query

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to escape a bracket in a pattern matching expression for PostgreSQL 8.2

The clause looks something like:

```
WHERE field SIMILAR TO '%UPC=\[ R%%(\mLE)%'
```

but I keep getting:

```
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: brackets [] not balanced
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select '%UPC=\[ R%%(\mLE)%';
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: select '%UPC=\[ R%%(\mLE)%';
               ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
     ?column?     
------------------
 %UPC=[ R%%(mLE)%
(1 row)
```

You need to set Postgres in [standard conforming strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) mode instead of backward compatible mode.

```
set standard_conforming_strings=1;
select '%UPC=\[ R%%(\mLE)%';
      ?column?      
--------------------
 %UPC=\[ R%%(\mLE)%
(1 row)
```

Or you need to use [escape string syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) which works regardless of mode:

```
set standard_conforming_strings=1;
select E'%UPC=\\[ R%%(\\mLE)%';
      ?column?      
--------------------
 %UPC=\[ R%%(\mLE)%
(1 row)

set standard_conforming_strings=0;
select E'%UPC=\\[ R%%(\\mLE)%';
      ?column?      
--------------------
 %UPC=\[ R%%(\mLE)%
(1 row)
```

You can [set this setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/config-setting.html) in postgresql.conf for all databases, using `alter database` for single database, using `alter user` for single user or group of users or using `set` for current connection.

Comment: I just used the escape string syntax and it worked. I forgot to escape the '\m' also and from there was the problem. Thanks!